# Date formatter for the google calender API

Tags: ios, nsdate

1) I am getting the date from the google calender. The format is **2013-05-03T22:30:00.000+02:00** like this. Which date format used for this type of date in the app.

2) I have to show the date like this format **Feb 4th 2013** .

How to implement these two features in the my app? Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the NSDate from that string:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS Z"];
 NSDate *myDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2013-05-03T22:30:00.000+02:00"];
```

Once you have your NSDate, you can do the same to get the representation:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:"MMM d yyyy"];
NSString *myString = [myDate stringFromDate:myDate];
```

You can consult the whole date formatting options here:

[Date Formatter Guide](http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/)

Comment: It's important that the 1st date formatter's locale be set to the special `en_US_POSIX` locale.

Answer (score 1):

The date is in [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) format. I suggest you to check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mwaterfall/953664) where you can see a category on `NSDate` called `NSDate (InternetDateTime)`. This will do the formatting for your input.

For your second question, check the usage of [`NSDateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html).