# Set Formatted NSDate in UILabel text

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uilabel, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have date which came from api and stored as `string` like

```
2013-05-09 09:30:00
```

and i want to show as

```
09-05-2013 09:30
```

in `UILabel`. I want to know how to use NSDateFormatter.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my answer to this question, you will get all the info you need here:

[Date formatter for the google calender API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339875/date-formatter-for-the-google-calender-api/16340101#16340101)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
        NSString *str = @"2013-05-09 09:30:00";
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        NSDate *dt = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
        NSString *str1 = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:dt];
        NSLog(@"Formated date - %@", str1);//output -> 09-05-2013 09:30

        lbl.text = str1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once go through this,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy''HH:mm"];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:162000];
NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",[formattedDateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@" "]);
```

Here `NSLog` Prints like `03-01-2001 02:30` , for more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) is apple document.

Hope it will helps you...

Comment: OP want show date as label text. But you not answer for that.